# diaporama image

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i did this code:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<script>
setInterval(function(){chrono('t');},1000);
</script>
<?php
include('function.php');
session_start();
global $list;
$list= captcha_list($_SESSION['id']);
global $i;
$i=0;
?>

<script>
function chrono(id){
inte= parseInt(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML,10);

switch(inte)
{
case 0:
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='7';


 break;
case 1:
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='0';
document.getElementById('im').src="<?php echo $list[$i]['captcha'];?>" ;


    break;
  case 2:
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='1';


    break;
  case 3:
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='2';
   break;
  case 4:
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='3';
  break;
  case 5:
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='4';
   break;
  case 5:
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='4';
    break;
  case 6:
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='5';
  break;
  case 7:
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='6';
<?php $i++; ?>

    break;
default:
    break;
}

};
</script>
<body style="background-image:url(paper_03.png)" >

 <form name="form_2"  style="background-image:url(paper_02.png);position: absolute; top:30px; left: 200px; width: 500px; height: 500px;" >
                    <CENTER>
                        <table style="position: relative; top:30px;" >
                    <tr><td colspan=4><label>Image will be refresh in <label id="t" name="t"> 7 </label>  seconds
                     </label></td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td height=200px ><label>Image </label></td><td></td><td height=200px colspan=2><input type="image" id="im" src="<?php echo $list[$i]['captcha'];?>" style=" height=150px" /> </td></tr>
                    <tr><td height=200px><label>Text </label></td><td colspan=3 height=200px><input type="text" name="cap" style="width: 400px" /> </td></tr>
                    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="answer" value="SUBMIT ANSWER" style="height:200%;background-image:url(paper_03.png)"/> </td><td><input type="submit" name="know" value="DON'T KNOW" style="height:200%; background-image:url(paper_03.png)"/> </td><td><input type="submit" name="pause" value="SUBMIT AND PAUSE" style="height:200%;background-image:url(paper_03.png)"/> </td>
                    </tr>


                </table>

    </CENTER>
</form>     
</body>
<footer>
<?php 
include('header_footer/footer.php');
?>
</footer>
</html>`

the problem is the first image displayed is the second one in array and the third one is never displayed.the changes is when timer=7 and timer=0.

- where is the error?
- what is it cause?
- how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This will change the image src.
Is that do you want?

```
var inte = 0;
setInterval(chrono,1000);

function chrono(){
  inte++;
  if(inte > 7) inte = 0;
  document.getElementById('im').src="paper_0" + inte + ".png";
};
```

Comment: i replaced the code as you suggest but the same result : only the second image then the first one are displayed

Comment: OK I see now, in what element you want to put the image or show the number?

Comment: for the number it is shown in `<label id="t" name="t"> 7 </label> ` with no problem. for  the image in `td height=200px colspan=2><input type="image" id="im" src="<?php echo $list[$i]['captcha'];?>" style=" height=150px" /> </td>`